# Remove files from source control GIT VScode

Tags: git

My entire desktop seems to be in the source control section in VS Code. How do i remove the files from source control without deleting 4000 files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+home+directory

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `.git` subdirectory of your desktop. It might be a hidden folder

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You might want to mark this as the accepted answer if it worked

Answer (score 2):

Delete the `.git` folder on your desktop. You can remove it from terminal/cmd or you can enable settings to view hidden files and folder. cause `.git` is hidden folder.